# How can you write dynamic dax queries so that they should work as stored procedures ( should accept few parameters)?

Tags: dax

i am new to DAX queries ,is there any way to write dax queries in dynamic way. So that they accept the parameters and executes the query with that parameters included(As stored procedures) and return values.

Answer (score 0):

EVALUATE FILTER(Tablename,AND( Tablename[columnname] =@parameter,tablename[columnname]=@parameter))

Comment: is there any way to pass the column name dynamically like EVALUATE FILTER(Tablename,AND( Tablename[@columnname] =@parameter,tablename@[columnname]=@parameter))